# ReactJS: How do I know which dependency made the useEffect hook run/trigger?

Tags: reactjs, dependencies, effect

Code example:

```
useEffect(() => {

//I want to know which was the variable which made the useffect run. var1 or var2. how can I?

}, [var1, var2]);
```

which dependency was used to make it run?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve the desired result without third-party libraries and a lot of code is to split `useEffect` into two `useEffect` hooks and one handler.

### Solution 1

```
const handler = () => {
    // ...some logic
};

useEffect(() => {
    // var1 has been changed
    handler();
}, [var1]);

useEffect(() => {
    // var2 has been changed
    handler();
}, [var2]);
```

### Solution 2

Use `useRef` to keep the previous state and then compare the results.

```
const prevVar1 = useRef();
const prevVar2 = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
    if(prevVar1.current !== var1) {
        // var1 has been changed
    }
    if(prevVar2.current !== var2) {
        // var2 has been changed
    }

    // and update the previous state
    prevVar1.current = var1;
    prevVar2.current = var2;

    // ...some logic
}, [var1, var1]);
```

### Solution 3

Or use the [use-what-changed](https://github.com/simbathesailor/use-what-changed) library

Comment: Be careful with Solution 1: If my understanding is correct, you should put handler function as dep to both hooks to avoid weird side-effects with old vars being used; then, add it in a useCallback to avoid re-executing on every render. And then, if useCallback depends on both variables, the hook will just re-execute like before... (but with more complicated code context)